# Check the Duplicates in column and highlight it

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I need to check the duplicates in `column B` I write following code which seems all right but instead I am getting `Run time Error` `13 type-mismatch` please help. why I am getting it?

```
Sub duplicate()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myRange = Columns("B:B")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then ' Run-time error 13 Type mismatch
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

**Update:**
*For further info follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drZK_-zzo_4*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need VBA to color duplicates. Just use conditional formatting:

[image]

But just for your interest what caused the error in your code is, that if you loop

```
For Each myCell In myRange
```

you actually don't loop through the cells in `myRange`, but through the columns of `myRange` which is only one (column B). If you want to loop through the cells of `myRange` you need to change it to

```
For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
```

otherwise `myCell.Value` is an array of the values of column B and therefore `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value)` failed.

---

If you really have to use VBA, I highly recommend to create the conditional formatting with VBA instead of your code. This will be much faster, your code is **extremely slow**.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateRuleForDuplicates()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Columns("B:B")
    With MyRange
        .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that if you run the code multiple times it will add a **new** rule every time. So you might want to delete all old rules in that range `.FormatConditions.Delete` before adding a new one `.AddUniqueValues`.

Comment: you are right but I need to place a button and add macro to it. can be done by recording macro but I am finding new ways

Comment: @IbneAshiq just to let you know your VBA code will be a lot slower than conditional formatting. So even if you have to use VBA, recording a macro that creates the rule for conditional formatting will be much faster than your code.